# Why is the .write method not working in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code that is supposed to write output onto another python file.
Here's a piece of my code so far.

```
file = open("collection.py","w")
collection1.extend(new)
print(collection)
file.write("collection = " + str(collection1))
file.close()
```

When I print the collection, it prints out what I want, which will be some list like `[1,2,3]`. But when I use the `.write` method, the file doesn't change at all - and yes, the file I want to write to is different than the list I want to write in it.

Comment: Did you mean collection or collection1? You print collection, but write collection1!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a file:

```py
collection1 = [1, 2, 3]
# w = write to file
# a = append to file
with open("collection.py", "w") as stream:
    stream.write("collection = " + str(collection1))
```

If you want to append more content to a file use `a` instead of `w`.

Prefer the `with` clause when possible over closing the file manually.

Comment: The code I wrote writes correctly the output to the file collection.py. Could you please show me what you get? What do you mean with "I am using mobile"?

Comment: Please instead of collection.py try adding the absolute path to the output  file.